# How to resolve form resubmission?

Tags: django, django-forms

When page refresh that post request, form resubmission happened.
I tried redirect after post request. but, it's not working when request have context. this context have form.errors because login.html show form error.
How to resolve this issue? (without Message Framework)

```
def do_login(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      email = form.cleaned_data['email']
      password = form.cleaned_data['password']
      user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
      if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return redirect(reverse('root'))
    else:
      pass
      # redirect cannot pass context, right?
  else:
    form = LoginForm()
context = {
    'form': form
}
return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', context=context)
```

Comment: As a sidenote, are you aware what you are trying to do comes [shipped with Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.login)?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is using the standard approach. You are redirecting after a successful post request, but not after an unsuccessful post. This allows the form to be displayed with errors.

If the user refreshes after an unsuccessful post, then the browser will usually warn the user that their data will be resubmitted. If they do resubmit, then it doesn't really matter, the login will fail again, and they will see the same errors as before.

Comment: yes, The code can show error. but I want stop form resubmission.

Comment: If you redirect to prevent resubmission you'll have to store the form errors somewhere, e.g. in the session or get parameters. That will be less reliable than the current code. Why is it important for you to prevent resubmission?